# How to convert PasswordAuthentication to Authenticator in Scala?

Tags: java, scala, converters

I'm writing authentication method in scala. This my function:

```
def getPasswordAuthentication(frm:String, psw:String):Authenticator=
{
    val authen = new PasswordAuthentication(frm, psw)
    return authen.asInstanceOf[Authenticator]
}
```

when i run this method occurred error.

**Error:** javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication cannot be cast to javax.mail.Authenticator

Here original Java code:

```
 Session.getDefaultInstance(mailProperties, new Authenticator(){
    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
        return new PasswordAuthentication(smtp_user, smtp_pass);
    }});
```

Then I modified to Scala.

Comment: The error says it all. You cannot cast incompatible types.

Comment: I need to open Session. It require two type:props, Authenticator. How can I cast?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do precisely what you are doing in your java code, get an instance of Authenticator after overriding the method getPasswordAuthentication.

```
def getPasswordAuthentication(uname:String, psw:String):Authenticator=
{
    new Authenticator(){
     def getPasswordAuthentication():PasswordAuthentication = {
        new PasswordAuthentication(uname, psw);
    }}
}
```

Comment: It works for override  def getPasswordAuthentication. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Um, you don't?  They are two entirely different classes.  You could, however, return an instance of an Authenticator with an overriden `getPasswordAuthentication()` method which returns the PasswordAuthentication instance in question.